# asyncpg.exceptions.InvalidAuthorizationSpecificationError Python PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu, ssl

I am making a Telegram bot in Python (Aiogram) with a PostgreSQL database. The database is running on Ubuntu 20.04 server and the bot is running on the same server. When I start the bot, it gives an error:

```
asyncpg.exceptions.InvalidAuthorizationSpecificationError: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "*server IP*", user "my_user", database "my_db", SSL off
```

`Postgresql.conf` file configured to `listen_addresses = '*'`, `pg_hba.conf` file on `host all all *my IP*/32 password`
In Python, I connect to PostgreSQL using Gino. If I run the bot on a local PC, everything works, it connects to the database on the server. But if the bot is running on the server, then I get an error. Please tell me how to configure permissions. Thanks

Comment: Does the censored IP address in the error message match the censored one in the hba file?

Comment: @jjanes No, in the error I see the server address, and in pg-hba I directly allow the connection through my local PC. That being said, when I run the python script on my local PC, it successfully connects to the database on the server.

Comment: @jjanes As I understand it, you need to allow the connection locally. But when I used the same entry as allowing connection from local PC, I was getting the same error.

Comment: No mystery here.  It allows you to connect from the IP address you told it to allow, and not from a different one.  Add another line to the hba for the other IP address.

Comment: @jjanes Added `host all all *server IP*/32 password` and still get the same error.

Comment: Did you reload after changing? Now does the error message ip address match the hba one?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help in the comments, I was able to fix the problem. I added a line to pg_hba.conf:

```
host all all *server IP*/32 password
```

and after that rebooted supervisor:

```
service supervisor restart
```